# ¿Por qué cuando ejecuto mi aplicación de Android Studio en el emulador la aplicación falla y me saca?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Android Studio, pero no puedo avanzar, ya que cuando ejecuto la aplicación para ver como va quedando el diseño, presiono el botón de "iniciar sesión" para entrar a la app y me saca, no se si estoy vinculando mal los botones o hay otro problema, ya que Android Studio no me señala ningún error. Por favor podrían ayudarme?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText user_name;
EditText Password;
Button login_Button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    user_name = findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    Password = findViewById(R.id.Password);
    login_Button = findViewById(R.id.login_Button);

    login_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(user_name.getText().toString().equals("Clarita") && Password.getText().toString().equals("1234")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡Inicio de sesión exitoso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //InicioSesion(v);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡Falló el inicio de sesión!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

//Metodo del boton iniciar sesión

```
/* public void InicioSesion(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} */
```

}

Luego he intentado hacerlo mediante un método pero no me ha funcionado, no entiendo cual es el error, también cuando "inicie sesión" debe llevarme a un fragmento de un menú en la barra inferior, yo supuse que si es fragmento seguramente necesite una conexión de actividad a fragmento, pero no entiendo como se realizaría en ese caso, de lo contrario no entiendo cual es el problema. Este es el código de la otra actividad a la que debería ir.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Toolbar toolbar;
FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setBackground(null);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int itemId = item.getItemId();
            if(itemId == R.id.bottom_money){
                openFragment(new moneyFragment());
                return true;
            } else if (itemId == R.id.bottom_location){
                openFragment(new locationFragment());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    openFragment(new moneyFragment());

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Estacionar Aquí", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if(itemId == R.id.nav_setting){

        openFragment(new settingFragment());

    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_home){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Inicio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }  else if (itemId == R.id.nav_login){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Cerrar sesión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

/*  Metodo utilizado para abrir un fragmento en una actividad:
*   Reemplaza el contenido del contenedor de fragmentos con el Fragment que se le pasa como parámetro,
*   luego confirma la transacción. */


//Fragmento abierto
private void openFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

Aquí dejo los errores que se presentaron en el LogCat, la verdad no los entiendo mucho, me seria de gran ayuda que se puedan resolver, ya que en los activity no me salta ningún error.

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sdems, PID: 26628 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ```
>
> ComponentInfo{com.example.sdems/com.example.sdems.MainActivity2}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
> bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
> Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
> your theme to use a Toolbar instead. at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has
> an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
> Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
> your theme to use a Toolbar instead. at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:185)
> at com.example.sdems.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:38) at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955) at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944) at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3531)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075) E
> Window handle Window{ae923fd u0 Application Error: com.example.sdems}
> has no registered input channel

Este es mi themes.xml, la verdad tengo dos archivos de esos, aquí se los dejo:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.SDEMS" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_lemon</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/green_lemon</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>


<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Este es el otro themes.xml (night):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.SDEMS" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Es importante revisar el LogCat, ¿Cuál es el error que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: He revisado el LogCat, y aparecen múltiples errores, estos son algunos: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sdems/com.example.sdems.MainActivity2}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Estos son otros errores del LogCat ¿Qué debo hacer?:                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)

Comment: Hola Lisa, bienvenida, para facilitar que te den una respuesta, agrega los mensajes de error en la pregunta (editándola), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: @lisa en el LogCat revisa donde dice "Caused by"

Comment: @Jorgesys esto es lo que dice: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias, lo siento, soy nueva en esto y no entendía bien las herramientas, tendré mas en cuenta como preguntar cuando lo haga nuevamente.

Comment: No te hagas problema, **nadie** entra a la plataforma sabiendo como hacer las cosas, de nuevo bienvenida!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se indica aquí:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has
> an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
> Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
> your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Este mensaje indica la solución del problema, ve al archivo `styles.xml` de tu proyecto, y define en tu tema la propiedad  [windowNoTitle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#windowNoTitle) con valor true:

```
<style .....>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

---

> [windowNoTitle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#windowNoTitle) : Bandera que indica si no debe haber ningún título
> en esta ventana. Puede ser un valor booleano, como "verdadero" o
> "falso".

---

Agrega `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` en tus dos archivos `themes.xml` :

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.SDEMS" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_lemon</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/green_lemon</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

themes.xml (night):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.SDEMS" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Que hago en el caso de no tener ese archivo? los únicos que tengo solo son los de colors.xml, strings.xml y dos archivos de themes, en ese caso eso deberia ir en el archivo themes.xml verdad? lo siento si son preguntas torpes pero soy nueva en esto.

Comment: @lisa gracias, he actualizado la respuesta, agrega en ambos .xml la propiedad <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> y prueba de nuevo

Comment: enserio Muchísimas gracias!!! ya funciona, enserio me ayudaste mucho, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

en tu archivo themes.xml en la etiqueta style deberia estar en esta forma:

```
<style name="Theme.TuAplicacion" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Ademas asegurate de que tengas importado esta clase

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

en mainActivyti2

Saludos

Comment: tengo dos archivos themes.xml , pero esa declaración solo lo tengo en un solo archivo themes.xml, debería estar en ambos?